# Graphics.DrawImage scaling method?

Tags: c#, graphics

Given the following code:

```
    var target = new Bitmap(source.Size.Width / 2, source.Size.Height / 2);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
    {
        g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, target.Size));
        g.Save();
        return target;
    }
```

What scaling method does 'DrawImage' use? Is it an average of 4 pixels? The value at {0,0)? Can I adjust this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: @mjwills I'm looking at it in DotPeek, and it appears to use InterpolationMode.Default. But I don't know what Default is.

Comment: InterpolationMode.Default is the same as Bilinear in .NET Core ([see source here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/dfcaf417005575df4a7e74cb562f89c964d7d689/src/libraries/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs#L143)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value of the [`Graphics.InterpolationMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.interpolationmode?view=net-5.0) property to the interpolation method that you want to use. This must be done before you call `DrawImage`.

Comment: Thanks, I suggest you add your comment to your answer so it is complete.